# C# : xml serialization of nodes with cyclic links

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, hyperlink, cyclic-dependency

I have a class Node something like this :

```
class Node {
    IEnumerable<Node> inputs;
}
```

Which basicly defines a simple graph.
I want to serialize my graph to a human-readable form, so normally I'd say xml would be the way to go.
But XML wasn't made with cyclic dependencies in mind :)

So - what would be the best way to go for serialization of my graph ?

I can think of a few ways :

- ditch XML, create my own format.
- use XML, tag each node with a unique ID, store connection-lists separate from the Nodes and resolve after loading

But I think other people must have had this same problem before, so there might be some better options.
Does anyone know of a solid approach ?

Answer (score 3):

For xml, I would go with the id approach (changing the DTO model such that it *isn't* cyclic).

Note that [`DataContractSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms405768.aspx) can support cyclic object graphs automatically by passing in `true` for the `preserveObjectReferences` option in the overloaded constructors; it won't be quite as simple as `XmlSerializer` output, but it will still be readable.

Answer (score 1):

If you switch to WCF DataContractSerializer, you can preserve the Object References (in 3.5 SP 1 and later)

```
[DataContract(IsReference=true)]
```

Sowmy has a good write up [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sowmy/archive/2006/03/26/561188.aspx)